# is there a productionDependencies like there is a devDependencies in node?

Tags: node.js, npm

I see that there is a devDependencies for only installing packages on the development server.  Does such a thing exist for only installing packages on the production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not a `productionDependencies` package.json attribute. To toggle on/off the installation of `devDependencies`, you'd could the `NODE_ENV` environment variable. See more [here](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html#production)
.

If that isn't enough, you could certainly define some custom scripts for npm that install production-specific dependencies, though. npm has support for [custom scripts](https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html), which you can read about here.

Answer (score 0):

you can skip installing the dev dependencies by executing `npm install --production`

You can also achieve the same by setting the **NODE_ENV** environment to production